# How to update derived state from props during rerender

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript

I have a component:

```
React = require 'react'

module.exports = Toolbar = React.createClass

  proptypes:
    initialUrl: React.PropTypes.string
    onUrlChange: React.PropTypes.func

  getInitialState: ->
    url: @props.initialUrl

  handleUrlChange: (e) ->
    @setState(url: e.target.value)

  handleUrlKeyUp: (e) ->
    if e.which == 13
      e.target.blur()
      if (url = @state.url.trim())? and url isnt @props.initialUrl
        @props.onUrlChange?(url)
        @setState {url}
    if e.which == 27
      @setState {url: @props.initialUrl}



  render: ->
    <div className="component-toolbar clearfix">
      <input type="text" value={@state.url} onChange={@handleUrlChange} onKeyUp={@handleUrlKeyUp}/>
    </div>
```

The component works like this:

1. It renders input with `initialUrl` inside.
2. User can change it.
3. When user hits enter, event `onUrlChange` is triggered.
4. When user hits esc, `@state.url` is returned to original value (`initialUrl`)

So far so good.

But when I change props or state of upper component, from which is derived `initalUrl` then component has the same state and is not rerendered. It's because of `getInitialState` is called only once. But what is the right approach to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) lifecycle function.

Comment: Yeah, it is a option. I tried it and it's ok, but it looks a bit ugly (hacky). Just wondering what is a right approach. This have to be a common problem I guess.

Comment: Using componentWillReceiveProps is the correct way to this. Why exactly do you think is it hacky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the way inputs in react work with initialValue, your current code has the same behavior. Only a remount would cause it to change the url.

As an alternative, how about having the parent manage the state, and add an onSubmit event?

```ruby
module.exports = Toolbar = React.createClass

  propTypes:
    url: React.PropTypes.string
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
    onSubmit: React.PropTypes.func
    onReset: React.PropTypes.func

  handleUrlChange: (e) ->
    @props.onChange(e.target.value)

  handleUrlKeyUp: (e) ->
    url = @props.url.trim()
    if e.which == 13
      e.target.blur()
      if url?
        @props.onChange?(url)
        @props.onSubmit?(url)
    if e.which == 27
      @props.onReset()

  render: ->
    <div className="component-toolbar clearfix">
      <input type="text" value={@props.url} onChange={@handleUrlChange} onKeyUp={@handleUrlKeyUp}/>
    </div>
```

Of course this would change the api of your component, but fear not! Because you start with a flexible stateless component, you can then wrap it in a stateful component that covers 90% of use cases (example in es6/7).

```js
class StatefulToolbar extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialUrl: React.PropTypes.string,
    onUrlChange: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {url: props.initialUrl};
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Toolbar 
        value={this.state.url}
        onChange={(url) => this.setState({url})}
        onReset={() => this.setState({url: this.props.initialUrl})}
        onSubmit={(url) => this.props.onUrlChange(url)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to control the value updating based on some other event, you should create a wrapper for that specific situation instead of making Toolbar complicated.

Side note: propTypes, not proptypes.